# How to get textchange event of textbox which is inside the jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery datatable and I have textbox in it for quantity field. When I enter a value in qty textbox the total amount should be calculated. Here is my code what I have tried. How do I catch textchange event for that textbox?
Please help me.

```
<table id="swcmtable" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Products</th>  
      <th>Quntity</th>  
      <th>Price</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>                        
</table>

<! -- I'm filling this datatable with JSON  --> 
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //function GetCart() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Defualt.aspx/GetData",
      data: JSON.stringify(),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        $("#swcmtable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        var textbox = '<input type="text" class="txtBox">';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
          $("#swcmtable").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].ProductName + "</td><td class=p >" + "<input type =text class= txtBox a> " + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Cost + "</td></tr>");
        }
      },
      error: function (result) {
        alert("Error " + result);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<script>
  var table = $('swcmtable').DataTable();
  var data = table.cell('.p');
  var txtdata = table.cell('.txtBox .a');
  $('#swcmtable tbody').on('Click', 'td', function () {
    $(txtdata).on('onchange', function () {
      alert("1");
      var celldata = table.cell(this).data();
      alert(celldata);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please Provide JsFillde or code snippets for fast answer

Answer (score -1):

You should write your logic in server side..

Comment: She is using JQuery Datatable. How can she write logic to render JQuery Datatable and textChange event of quantity textbox at server side?